# object looking weird due to normal map (unsure if this is the actual problem)

Tags: unity

ok when making a room for unity I created a material that I use for the walls unfortunately it does not turn out the way I want it to in unity
this is what it looks like in blender
[image]
this is what it looks like in unity
[image]
this is the normal map
[image]

Comment: That looks like a rather "strong" normal map, is there any chance turning down either the strength or the distance (not sure of the settings in unity) substantially (as low as 0.1) fixes things? The other thing I'm thinking is that it may be a DirectX/OpenGL thing (less likely) - blender uses OpenGL for shading, and Unity can handle both, so make sure your unity settings are for OpenGL

Comment: it seems to be more an issue with the walls itself each of them are shaded differently and i don't know how to fix it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EQ6sYs2kjzmKuli_9Tn3tVPfj70cguhy/view?usp=sharing here is what it looks like without the material